# setTitle AlertDialog holoeverywhere crashes?

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I get an get error when I use setTitle on AlertDialog with Holoeverywhere ...

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.holoeverywhere.app.Dialog$DialogTitle cannot be cast to org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView
at org.holoeverywhere.widget.AlertController.setupTitle(AlertController.java:719)
at org.holoeverywhere.widget.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:750)
at org.holoeverywhere.widget.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:469)
at org.holoeverywhere.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:411)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:351)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:256)
at com.droidersuin.project.setting.ProfileActivity$8.onClick(ProfileActivity.java:432)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
                    builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
                            startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) {

                            if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) {
                                getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                                mImageCaptureUri = null;
                            }
                        }
                    } );
```

There is an error at `builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");`

How do I fix it?

Comment: Post your full activity code.

Comment: Post your xml file with related code.

Answer (score 0):

Please use AlertDialog as follows

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                this);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked
                                    //write code for the click of yes button
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked
                                         //write code for the click of No button
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
```